# CSS-design issue for text box changing in chrome

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Site is working fine in Firefox but coming to Google chrome search box width is increasing.i given

```
width 450px;
```

but the width is warying from chrome to Firefox

take a look : http://qa.myhealth.today/myhealth/

see in header you will find search box.

Comment: i tried % but its not working

Comment: [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/1xdqLcj0/). Please post your HTML and CSS so we can help you out.

Comment: i given demo link in my question...

Answer (score 1):

```
#nav-searchbar{    
display: table-caption; 
}
```

you can try like this .

Comment: yugi it worked fine in chrome but after applying this ...total search box is not displaying in ie